# Can you use the Administer First Aid skill on yourself?

Tags: skills, targeting, pathfinder-2e

The [Administer First Aid skill](https://pathfinder2.dragonlash.com/skills/medicine/administer-first-aid/) has the text:

> perform first aid on an adjacent creature

Which seems to imply that you can’t use this skill on yourself, as the target must be another creature, but I just wanted to double check.

**Can you use the Administer First Aid skill on yourself?**

Comment: Hi Kethryll, welcome to rpg.se! I made a quick edit to make your question a bit easier to read. If you dislike what I have done you and rollback the changes or [edit] it further. When you get a chance take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn about the site. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 4):

### No

While adjacency isn't defined, other text shows that you are not considered adjacent to yourself. Specifically, looking at the related [Battle Medicine](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=760) skill feat (p258)

> You can patch up **yourself or an adjacent ally**, even in combat...'

You can see the methodology is that "you" and "an adjacent ally" are two different valid targets for the Battle Medicine ability. If an ability can target you, it says so specifically. You're [not even considered your own ally](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=353) (as was the case in 1e), for the purposes of targeting.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, but because (as you have shown) 'you are not your own ally'. Not because you are not adjacent to yourself - which I'm not convinced the rules or your example shows (that said, I like that you pointed out that it wasn't defined - and verify that I also can't find a definition).

Answer (score -1):

No.

You must perform it on an adjacent creature as per the quoted ability text.  You are not considered to be adjacent to yourself.

Comment: This could be improved by including the rules (or dictionary definition if rules don't address it) for adjacency.